# Запятушончонка или точка с нею?

Tags: пунктуация

Можно взамен простой запятой (1.) – чтобы обозначить гнаницы – здесь поставить точку с ней (2.)?

> 1. Есть одиннадцать глаголов: ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, висеть, смотреть, терпеть, зиждеться, зибеться, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать, дышать, которые, будучи глаголами II спр., имеют окончания, характерные I-му.

> 2. Есть одиннадцать глаголов: ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, висеть, смотреть, терпеть, зиждеться, зибеться, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать, дышать; которые, будучи глаголами II спр., имеют окончания, характерные I-му.

Comment: Так себе правки. Два текста сократили до одного — это хорошо. Но вот этот «(?)» знак следовало разместить __вместо__ запятой перед _которые_. А заголовок зачем исправлять? Это как бы его стиль, да и всем понятно, что в заголовке.

Comment: Как скажете, Максим! Хорошо, что Вы участвуете в *оформлении* вопросов-ответов! Вот только я не знаю — **как** откатить собственную правку. Подскажите. **Враз поправлю**.

Comment: @Максим Для того, чтобы ваше сообщение "Так себе правки..." попало ко мне, нужно было поставить значок *@РиммаМихайлова*. Я обнаружила Ваше сообщение-мнение совершенно случайно (после нового ответа *Sharon*).

Comment: @Максим Нашла — как. Откатила. Пусть будет "по-вашененовскому". Такого пунктуационного знака, правда, нет — ***точка с запятушончонкой***.

Comment: А я тут при чем?.. И почему такая подчеркнуто разговорная стилизация  в комментариях?

Comment: Не-не, *Sharon*, Вы здесь совершенно ни при чем. А *словеччечульчечек* ведь можно **изпронадприповыдумать** сколько угодно — до абсурда... *Запятутончулечка, запятуленция, запятушкулька, запятушкулечка, запятушкулюлечка...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вопрос на сообразительность и внимательность.

1. *Зиждеться, зибеться* — таких слов нет.
   Есть *зиждиться* и *зыбиться* — это изолированные глаголы. Они здесь лишние.
   Ещё: не "висе́ть", а "зави́сеть".
2. *Характерные I-му*
   Римские цифры пишутся без наращения.
   Управление: [характерный](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/2441/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) **для кого-чего** (не кому-чему).
3. > *На столе были разложены всевозможные предметы: книги, письменные принадлежности, географические карты, — которыми хозяин, по-видимому, давно не пользовался* — тире необходимо, чтобы показать, что придаточная часть относится ко всем однородным членам, точнее, к обобщающему слову.

Ни о какой точке с запятой здесь речи быть не может.  Ставим запятую и тире.

4. Вносим все исправления, получаем:

*Есть одиннадцать глаголов: ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, смотреть, терпеть, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать, дышать, — которые, будучи глаголами II спр., имеют окончания, характерные для I.* [или для первого]

[зыбиться](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/70058)
[зиждиться](https://lopatin.academic.ru/42883/%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
[Сочетания знаков препинания. Запятая и тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176#pp176)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149151/discussion-on-answer-by--------3); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагается вариант:

*Есть одиннадцать глаголов: **ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, смотреть, терпеть, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать и дышать,** которые, будучи глаголами II спр., имеют глагольные **СУФФИКСЫ**, характерные для I спр.*

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** **Глагольные/тематические суффиксы**, **а не окончания!**

Для последнего однородного члена используем союз ***И***, а после него ставим **запятую**.

Такая графика выглядит красиво. Сочетание знаков (запятая и тире) выглядит **как  единый знак**, а такой сильный знак здесь **совершенно неуместен.**

**ОБОСНОВАНИЕ**

**[Розенталь §89. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах, пункт 3 (примечание)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/43.htm)**

Если постановка **ЗАПЯТОЙ** требуется структурой последней части предложения (стоящей после перечисления), то тире **ОПУСКАЕТСЯ** и ставится только запятая, например: *Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, **как-то: муку, пеньку, мед и прочее**, но покупает только небольшие безделушки...* (Гоголь).

В нашем случае запятая ставится **перед придаточным предложением.**

Comment: То вы за "побуквенно", то нарушаете эту букву, не ссылаясь ни на какое правило (других же часто просите привести доказательства), то вам не нравится тире перед "которые", а сейчас оно появляется и занимается поглотительством... Я всеми руками – за красивую графику, только чтоб грамматика не хромала. Я также за нововведения, если что-то не описано в источниках. // Почему вы оставили глагол "висеть", сюда не вписывающийся?

Comment: А мне так нравится! Я выбираю знаки на границе между блоками: запятая,  тире, единый знак. Это нонсенс  – ставить единый знак перед придаточным определительным. Запятую поставить не могу: сольется с однородным рядом, так что остается тире. Интересное дело, а грамматика-то у меня почему хромает? Это у  вас графика хромает и не позволяет мне правильно прочитать грамматику. И вопрос к вам (из космоса). У нас встречаются случаи каннибализма среди знаков. По какому правилу вы определяете, кто кого съест.

Comment: 1. Сочетание знаков (запятая и тире) **всегда** выглядит как единый знак. Вообще, это мутный знак. Мы часто ставим запятую перед тире, например чтобы закрыть придаточное, и не говорим о едином знаке. 2. Между блоками ставится двоеточие, точка с запятой, но не запятая. Ещё раз: блоки – это большие, сложные предложения со своими запятыми и тире. 3. Грамматика хромает потому, что вы не открыли придаточное. 4. Про кто кого съест подумаю завтра. На сегодня спокойной ночи :))...

Comment: ОК, давно пора спать.  Меня более всего интересует последнее, а все остальное риторика, не более того.

Comment: Да, еще тире между блоками тоже может быть, но придаточное не может быть блоком, оно включается в блок с главным. До встречи в эфире!

Comment: Спасибо за дискуссию. Я пока решила не обсуждать на форуме тему блоков.

Comment: Шэрон, почему вы проигнорировали замечание насчёт "висеть"?

Comment: Извините, моя невнимательность. А как вам нравится "окончания и суффиксы" в записи?

Comment: Не знаю, в морфемы не хочу лезть. Вроде бы в этой теме всегда говорят об окончаниях личных форм глаголов.

Comment: По-моему там ошибка: 11 глаголов  II спр. имеют окончания  I  спряжения. Это как?

Comment: Кстати, я поставила союз И по вашему замечанию: "В этом примере: ...муку, пеньку, мед и прочее, но... есть "и", что показывает конец перечисления".

Comment: Имеются в виду концовки в начальной форме,  -**е**ть. //  О! Вот за это плюс.

Comment: Но концовка отличается от окончания, а вот тематические/глагольные суффиксы А и Е как раз и характерны для I спряжения. // Я всегда внимательно слушаю критику))  Ведь в "моих блоках" было 3 варианта,  и я решила выбрать запятую и союз И.

Comment: Ну суть-то в этом: видим Е, а в остальных формах И и Я, поэтому и относим их ко II спр. У Леопольда вообще всё перекручено...

Comment: Перекручено или нет, но почему другие участники не видят этой ошибки? Это говорит о небрежности в какой-то мере, не так ли? А ведь исправить ее было несложно.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагается еще один вариант оформления:

*Есть одиннадцать глаголов — **ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, смотреть, терпеть, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать, дышать**, — которые, будучи глаголами II спр., имеют глагольные суффиксы, характерные для I спр.*

Это оформление однородного ряда по правилам для **вставных конструкций.** Двумя тире выделен ряд, запятая перенесенная, ставится перед придаточным предложением.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Почему в данном случае удобно применить **вставную конструкцию?**

1. Дело в том, что обычно обобщающее слово **согласовано** с членами ряда в числе и падеже, что мы видим на примере **из Розенталя:** *На столе были разложены всевозможные **предметы**: книги, письменные принадлежности, географические карты, — которыми хозяин, по-видимому, давно не пользовался*.

Там тире ставится в качестве **дополнительного знака** [(пункт 2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176#pp176), чтобы показать отнесенность придаточного к обобщающему слову (*предметы, а не карты*).

2. В заданном предложении **нет согласования** обобщающего слова и членов ряда, поэтому тем более нужно обозначить, что союзное слово КОТОРЫЕ относится к сочетанию "одиннадцать глаголов". И вставка в этом случае нагляднее передает такую **отнесенность.**

Здесь по сути нет обобщения, но есть значение **пояснения** (какие именно глаголы).

Comment: Тоже верно, голосую.

Comment: Думаю, что оба варианта – с двоеточием в начале либо с тире в начале, но по-любому с точкой с запятой в конце – хороши.

Comment: (1) Сэр, точка с запятой по значению очень близка  к точке (нечто среднее между ними). Разделить фразу на две части можно следующим образом: Есть одиннадцать особых глаголов:  ненавидеть, вертеть, обидеть, зависеть, смотреть, терпеть, видеть, гнать, держать, слышать, дышать; эти глаголы,  будучи...    (2) Of the two good options, you have to choose one, don't you?  И вот тире представляется мне лучшим знаком по сравнению с двоеточием, при этом они обозначают разную грамматику.  So take your pick, sir.